# Предпочтительный формат и/или тип данных для хранения ссылок на сайты в БД

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Для меня является очень неудобным хранить закладки на сайты в браузере, так как при очередной переустановке забываешь их сохранить...

По этой причине я решил попробовать написать программу (для себя) для удобного перехвата ссылок из буфера обмена или при выделении в тексте и последующего хранения в отдельном файле (БД). Не подскажите ли, какой тип данных больше подойдёт для этих целей и корректно будет обрабатываться? Спасибо.

Comment: @prog_god, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Чем вас не устраивает облачная синхронизация? Большинство браузеров поддерживает данную опцию.

А по вопросу - **varchar(255)**, возможно, не хватит каким-то хитромудрым ссылкам со множеством параметров, поэтому **text**.

Comment: @jackrv, насколько знаю, по стандарту 256 - это предел

upd: по стандарту 255 - это рекомендация, де-факто может быть и длиннее, но у меня есть сомнения, что такие попадут в закладки.

Comment: В любом случае не вижу смысла изобретать что-то новое. Каким динозавром пользуется автор, что собирается свой агрегатор ссылок изобретать?

А касаемо ссылок 225(226) символов - теоретически достаточно, но бывают же многоуровневые ссылки, в которых хранится не только адрес старницы, но еще и пол/кол-во детей/сумма долга по кредиту разработчика и пользователя и еще несколько полезных данных, общей суммой по символам более 500.